# I'm trying to debug a haxe program in visual studio code but Type:Error Cannot read properties of null (reading 'toString')

Tags: visual-studio-code, haxe

[debug error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/svrhC.jpg)

you can find the code [here](https://gitlab.com/dpzbusinezz/canaanrebornopensource)

under canaanreborn2020prealpha/game-master

I was trying to haxe compile.hxml but Field drawContent overrides parent class with different or incomplete type so I thought debuggin will help me understand what they wanted to achive with drawContent to correct it

I figured out this

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense para saber los atributos posibles.
    // Mantenga el puntero para ver las descripciones de los existentes atributos.
    // Para más información, visite: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "cwd": "./game-master",
            "args": ["compile.hxml"],
            "name": "Haxe Interpreter",
            "type": "haxe-eval",
            "request": "launch"
        }
    ]
}
```

for the launch.json